# No module named 'resource' installing Apache Spark on Windows

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark

I am trying to install apache spark to run locally on my windows machine. I have followed all instructions here https://medium.com/@loldja/installing-apache-spark-pyspark-the-missing-quick-start-guide-for-windows-ad81702ba62d.

After this installation I am able to successfully start pyspark, and execute a command such as

```
textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
```

When I then execute a command that operates on textFile such as

```
textFile.first()
```

Spark gives me the error 'worker failed to connect back', and I can see an exception in the console coming from worker.py saying 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named resource'. Looking at the source file I can see that this python file does indeed try to import the resource module, however this module is not available on windows systems. I understand that you can install spark on windows so how do I get around this?

Comment: As below, a change was introduced in Spark 2.4.0 which breaks worker.py on Windows. For now, downgrading to 2.3.2 works. I have raised this as an issue [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26080)

Comment: Check out my answer if you want Spark 2.4.0

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I struggled the whole morning with the same problem. Your best bet is to downgrade to Spark 2.3.2

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't specifically need version 2.4.0 so this works for me

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the same issue for me.

Comment: I wish I could say the same. After I  got the same error after rolling back to 2.3.2 I rolled hadoop back as well to 2.7.7 but alas, I still get the error.

Comment: MT, also try commenting 127.0.0.1 on your \System32\drivers\etc\hosts file

Answer (score 11):

The fix can be found at https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/23055.

The resource module is only for Unix/Linux systems and is not applicaple in a windows environment. This fix is not yet included in the latest release but you can modify the worker.py in your installation as shown in the pull request. The changes to that file can be found at https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/23055/files.

You will have to re-zip the pyspark directory and move it the lib folder in your pyspark installation directory (where you extracted the pre-compiled pyspark according to the tutorial you mentioned)

Comment: This solved the problem for me thanks! I did copy the worker.py and replaced it in my Spark folder. I zipped the pyspark folder in the spark folder and replaced the \user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\python\lib. I did not have to downgrade anymore.

Comment: Hi @ruedi  I didnt findt "worker.py" in that repository, I just find the commits, where it is ? thanks in advance

Comment: you have to click "view file" on the top right corner of the commit window of the worker.py (https://github.com/HyukjinKwon/spark/blob/5fe1c0976acaaca444d98ce0dff82eb92d82076a/python/pyspark/worker.py)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to all those valuable answers,

For windows users,Make sure you have copied the correct version of the winutils.exe file(for your specific version of Hadoop) to the spark/bin folder

Say,
     if you have Hadoop 2.7.1, then you should copy the winutils.exe file from the Hadoop 2.7.1/bin folder

Link for that is here

https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils

Answer (score 0):

I edited worker.py file. Removed all resource-related lines. Actually `# set up memory limits` block and `import resource`. The error disappeared.