# SocketTimeoutException when trying to run PySpark app from PyCharm

Tags: pyspark, pycharm

This is my first Python app that I'm trying to run on Spark. I have had no problems before running scala apps in server or standalone.

I start pyspark on another command window like the following:

```
C:\Users\jesaremi>conda activate py3.6

(py3.6) C:\Users\jesaremi>pyspark --master local[1]
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec 30 2018, 18:50:55) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
2019-01-23 09:05:45 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.6.8 (default, Dec 30 2018 18:50:55)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
```

And here's my python script which is copied over from somewhere else:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('MyFirstStandaloneApp')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

text_file = sc.textFile("./shakespeare.txt")

counts = text_file.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
             .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
             .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)

print ("Number of elements: " + str(counts.count()))
counts.saveAsTextFile("./shakespeareWordCount")
```

The project interepreter in my PyCharm is set to Python 3.6 which I created my self and it contains important packages such as pyspark and py4j

The result of the run is the following:

```
C:\Users\jesaremi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py3.6\python.exe D:/Projects/HelloSpark/Main.py
2019-01-23 09:17:27 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
2019-01-23 09:17:28 WARN  Utils:66 - Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 1]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jesaremi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\jesaremi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 25, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'resource'
2019-01-23 09:17:40 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PairwiseRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:55)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:135)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:409)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:199)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:545)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:513)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:164)
    ... 18 more
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apparently PySpark 2.4 is messed up and you need to downgrade to 2.3.2 on Windows.

See this for more details:

[No module named 'resource' installing Apache Spark on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53273017/no-module-named-resource-installing-apache-spark-on-windows)