# Setting default log level to "WARN" in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, log4j

I have installed Spark because I need pyspark. I have this problem:

Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).

[image]

This is the log4j.properties file:

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Set the default spark-shell log level to WARN. When running the spark-shell, the
# log level for this class is used to overwrite the root logger's log level, so that
# the user can have different defaults for the shell and regular Spark apps.
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=WARN

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR

# SPARK-9183: Settings to avoid annoying messages when looking up nonexistent UDFs in SparkSQL with Hive support
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry=ERROR
```

Python was already installed and works well. 
How can I solve?

Comment: I'm not seeing a problem. The message on the terminal about setting the logging level is just an informational message, if you chose to change the logging to be more or less verbose. That is a standard message, even in the other spark shell languages.

Comment: I thought the message was a problem because any code I run generates an error. Evidently the problem is another and perhaps I am identifying it. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can you post a sample of the code and the error it generates?

Comment: For the moment it seems to work. Maybe the errors were due to problems with versions of spark that I'm trying to solve.

Comment: The error is: ImportError: No module named 'resource'. It seems to be a module only for UNIX, while I use Windows. Is there a way to solve?

Comment: Looks to be related to spark 2.4. There is a fix by modifying `worker.py`, as documented in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53935664/2639647. Or you can downgrade to the latest in the 2.3 line.

Comment: Thanks! The error seems solved by installing spark 2.3.2 instead of spark 2.4.0.